# How to reset LinkedIn Client Secret?

Tags: linkedin-api

For security, I regularly rotate all the secret keys for my application. There doesn't seem to be any way to reset or revoke the Client Secret for LinkedIn apps, however.

Am I missing something obvious? Or is it not possible to reset/revoke my LinkedIn Client Secret?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for something that is not possible. It's like trying to change your own private key on a regular basis.

In a worst-case scenario, if you ever get compromised, you can always create a new LinkedIn app.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am going to leave the question open for a little while longer before accepting this answer. It's possible with Google, Facebook, Twitter, and every other API that we use, so I find it odd that LinkedIn wouldn't support this.

Using your key example, I'm not trying to change my private key. I want to generate a new private key, assign that to my LinkedIn app, and revoke the privileges of the old key so it can't be used any more. This is a common feature with APIs.